# "The keyword 'interface' is reserved" when using LernaJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lerna

Can not seem to run NextJs in development (`next dev`) when using [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/). I can get other files to pull in just fine (e.g images) but it doens't seem to process TS on the fly using this method. Anybody have any thoughts on this?

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import React from "react";
| 
> interface Props {
|   name: string;
| }
```

packages/shared/components/Example.tsx

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  name: string;
}

export const Example = ({ name }: Props) => {
  return <div>Name: {name}</div>;
};
```

packages/web/pages/index.tsx

```
import { Example } from "shared/components/Example";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [something that is being worked on/considered](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/13542) and supposedly [might actually work already in some cases](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9474#issuecomment-642717331), but I was not able to make `baseUrl` work for me.

In the mean time [per Jacob Rask's suggestion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9474#issuecomment-557278243) you should use [next-transpile-modules](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules). I was struggling with this issue myself, and this finally worked!